# Числа Фибоначчи. Объяснить код

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, числа-фибоначчи

**Дано:**
Для решения задачи считываем два целых числа i и j такие, что 1 ≤ i, j ≤ 10^6.

**Найти:**
Нужно вывести остаток от деления НОД чисел Fi и Fj на 10^9.

**Решение:**
По свойству из Википедии: «Наибольший общий делитель двух чисел Фибоначчи равен числу Фибоначчи с индексом, равным наибольшему общему делителю индексов», получаем, что НОД(F_n,F_m) = F_{НОД(n,m)}.

Значит, нам нужно найти НОД для чисел i и j из условия, после чего найти соответствующее число Фибоначчи по модулю 1000000000.

**Код от Harry:**

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int nod(int a, int b) // Алгоритм Евклида
{
    while (a && b) if (a > b) a %= b; else b %= a;
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j; // вводимые числа

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("INPUT.TXT");
    fin >> i >> j; // считываем i и j
    fin.close();

    int F0 = 0, F1 = 1; // по условию

    for (i = nod(i, j); i > 0; --i)  // ищем нужное число..
    {
        int F = (F0 + F1) % 1000000000;// .. по модулю 1000000000
        F0 = F1;
        F1 = F;
    }

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("OUTPUT.TXT");
    fout << F0; //остаток от деления НОД чисел Fi и Fj на 10^9
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Я не очень понимаю фразу: "после чего найти соответствующее число Фибоначчи по модулю 1000000000". Может ли кто-то объяснить ее и соответствующую часть кода подробнее? Т.е. вот эту:

```
for (i = nod(i, j); i > 0; --i)  // ищем нужное число..
{
    int F = (F0 + F1) % 1000000000;// .. по модулю 1000000000
    F0 = F1;
    F1 = F;
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос не про программирование, но результат операции x % y - число x по модулю y (что собственно и написано в коде и комменте к нему)

Comment: Число по модулю N это остаток от деления на n. Для операций сложения работает правило (a + b) mod n = (a mod n + b mod n) mod n. Соответственно на каждом шаге для поиска k-того числа Фибоначчи по mod n можно складывать 2 предыдущих, которые тоже найдены по mod n. Условие для того, чтобы у тебя int не переполнился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти соответствующее число Фибоначчи по модулю 1000000000 - значит находим число Фибоначчи и берем остаток от деления его на 1000000000.

```
for (i = nod(i, j); i > 0; --i)  // ищем нужное число..
```

Тело цикла выполнится столько раз, сколько вернула функция `nod`. Если вернулось 3, то i примет значения 3, 2, 1, и когда станет 0, в цикл мы уже не войдем.

```
{
    int F = (F0 + F1) % 1000000000;// .. по модулю 1000000000
```

Находим следующее число Фибоначчи по модулю 1000000000 (оператор `%` находит остаток от деления). Если не находить остаток на каждой итерации, типа чтобы потом 1 раз в конце посчитать, тогда случится переполнение и ответ испортится.

```
    F0 = F1;
    F1 = F;
```

Большее число записывается на место меньшего, а новое - на место большего. Ну например:
3, 5 было
5, 8 стало

```
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А почему выводим не F, например, а F0?

Comment: @ИраЗлобина переменная F объявлена внутри цикла и существует только в нем, к ней нельзя обратиться за пределами цикла. Да и вернуть нам нужно число с правильным индексом, для примера возьмем 0. Цикл выполнится 0 раз, и мы вернем F0 = 0 (F1 нельзя брать это будет число с индексом 1 уже а не 0). Если бы цикл выполнился 1 раз, в F0 было бы 1.